# disable checkbox on treepanel child ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

i have treepanel code in extjs view, here it is:

```
createTreePaketExist: function() {
        var groupProduct = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            store       : 'TreePaketModif',
            queryMode   : 'local',
            itemId      : 'treeProduct',
            renderTo    : Ext.getBody(),
            name        : 'treeProduct',
            rootVisible : false,
            useArrows   : true,
            layout      :'fit',
            margin      : '0 0 0 0',
            autoScroll  : true,
            height      : 150,
            width       : '63%',
            listeners: 
            {
                checkchange: function(node, checked, eOpts){
                if (node.isLeaf()) {
                    node = node.parentNode;
                    var siblingStateEqual = true;
                    if (node.childNodes.length == 1) {
                        siblingStateEqual = checked;
                    } else {
                        node.cascadeBy(function(n) {
                        if (n != node) {
                            if (n.get('checked') != checked) {
                            siblingStateEqual = false;
                            }
                        }
                        });
                    }
```

i got result like this:
[image]

i want to disabled or delete checkbox in `Program Indihome 1000 menit-IN1000`, what must i add or edit?
thanks..

Comment: Can you show more code or setup a fiddle at http://fiddle.sencha.com to demonstrate your checkbox tree.

Comment: i just show the result in picture, this `store` has much file. so i can show it all

Comment: Show more of your code as currently I cannot see how/where you are making it a checked tree.